# save images outside cakephp, save it to codeigniter assets folder cakephp upload plugin

Tags: php, codeigniter, cakephp, image-uploading

I am using `josegonzalez/cakephp-upload` plugin for cakePHP. Originally it stores the uploaded images to `app/webroot/img/files/[modelname]/[idname]`. But `cakePHP` in my case is used inside a `CodeIgniter` installation and I want to save my images to the `assets` directory of my `CodeIgniter`. Is there a possible way to edit the `UploadBehavior` of the upload plugin? I tried like this,

```
    'rootDir' => '/localhost/ci_installation/',
    'pathMethod' => 'primaryKey',
    'path'  => '{ROOT}assets{DS}images{DS}{model}{DS}',
```

I edited the `rootDir` to my local installation of `CI` but after uploading, the images are not stored in `/localhost/ci_installation/assets/images/` location. Can somebody help me with this? Please? Thank you so much.

Comment: `but after uploading, the images are not stored in /localhost/ci_installation/assets/images/` - well where are they stored?

Comment: My answer below, its path which you should edit, and have in mind that ROOT comes from CakePHP constants make sure its set correctly, you also can try to debug the value of the path to see if thats the place where your files are stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change 'path' which uses ROOT global(cakephp) with the path you want. 
Change this line:

```
 'path'  => '{ROOT}assets{DS}images{DS}{model}{DS}',
```

to

```
 'path'  => '{CI_IMG_ROOT}assets{DS}images{DS}{model}{DS}',
```

and add to Config/bootstrap.php

```
 define('CI_IMG_ROOT','/whatever-root-dir-you-want-here/')
```

Change ROOT to CT_IMG_ROOT or something that will point to your desired location

Check this  [Global constant and functions CakePHP Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html)

Comment: `CI_IMG_ROOT` will be defined as a constant in bootstrap.php or how would I define it inside bootstrap.php?

Comment: If you are using CakePHP bootstrap.php is the right place. You have to go to the file and define it yourself with define() function http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php to be honest you dont have to use global you can set 'path' => with-anything-you-want pointing to right directory, you can use simple variable, but global is useful as you will probably want to change it one day you will have to change it only in this one place

Comment: If I use `'path'  => '{CI_IMG_ROOT}assets{DS}images{DS}{model}{DS}',`, it will still be stored inside the cakePHP. I wanted it to be stored outside the cakephp directory.

Comment: You did not udnerstand my answer I suppose. make it: define('CI_IMG_ROOT','C:\www\whatever-root-dir-you-want-here') or define('CI_IMG_ROOT','/var/www/whatever-root-dir-you-want-here')

Comment: This was the error `move_uploaded_file(C:\xampp\htdocs\hmvc\admincms\app\http:\localhost\hmvc\assets\images/26\uimg.png) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Invalid argument [APP\Plugin\Upload\Model\Behavior\UploadBehavior.php, line 368]` instead of `'path'  => '{CI_IMG_ROOT}assets{DS}images{DS}{model}{DS}',` i used `'path'  => CI_IMG_ROOT`, where `CI_IMG_ROOT` is defined in bootstrap.php as `define('CI_IMG_ROOT', Router::fullbaseUrl().'/hmvc/assets/images');`. Am I missing something?

Comment: And by the way, `C:\xampp\htdocs\hmvc` is my `CI` installation, inside it is `admincms` where I am using `cakephp`.

Comment: That is what I used. I defined `CI_IMG_ROOT` as `define('CI_IMG_ROOT', Router::fullbaseUrl().'/hmvc/assets/images');`. Then I used the defined constant like this, `path => '{CI_IMG_ROOT}assets{DS}images{DS}{model}{DS}'` .

Comment: You are almost there, Router::fullbaseUrl() returns http:\xxxx , you need C:\xxxx\xxx path, So: define('CI_IMG_ROOT', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/hmvc/assets/images/'); and set your 'path' => path => '{CI_IMG_ROOT}' you can play with {model} later

Comment: It's no use. Followed your instruction on your latest comment but still the images are still stored inside my `cakephp` directory. *sigh

Comment: This was the answer by the way. I reviewed your comments and it all made sense. I just need to modify the code in my model, the portion `path => CI_IMG_ROOT`, just all that. Thanks man.

Comment: You could just as easily do `'path'  => '/whatever-root-dir-you-want-here/assets...` it's not _necessary_ to use the constant dereferencing.

Comment: I mentioned it in one of comments above, 'path' => with-anything-you-want.. pointing to right directory, but I think its good to use constant because as he is uploading images he will probably want to show/use them and its gonna be as easy as grabing the const, not mentioning situation when you will want to change the directory but thats just my opinion, anyways @AD7six thanks for CakePHP! :)